# Limiting 14V current to 50A

Tags: dc, battery-charging, generator, solar-energy, alternator

Given multiple possible powerful charge sources without adequate over-current protection, and a very large (say 500 AH) depleted battery bank, using a very low resistance / high acceptance rate chemistry.

50A is just an example, the goal is to "stack" more powerful charge sources in parallel until the user knows that the peak current demands of the bank are satisfied; the next step up would be 100, then 150 amps, etc.

If resources were unlimited, we could start out at say 5C (say 2500A) and work down, but they are not.

What are some components, circuits I could use to limit the source current to these power levels, starting with the 50A example?
If a single off the shelf device exists, that would be ideal, but I suspect not.

Comment: Do you realize that limiting 14V to 50A in a simple way might mean that you will produce 700 W and have to get rid of that? A more complex design would use a DC/DC converter with a current controlled output, which is still a complex design at such a power level. A bunch of car headlights in parallel might not be ideal but it is fairly simple and cheap to design. (And it gives a nice visual feedback about waht is happening.)

Comment: PNP/PFET pass transistor, current sense resistor, reference and an opamp?

Comment: Made question less like a shopping question and more like a design question. Don't close

Comment: What's a 'charge source'?

Comment: Really? examples could include a high output alternator, mains power supply, an even larger battery bank, a huge solar array, wind, hydro, whatever!

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen please explain the headlights thing, as if I'm five.

Comment: @laptop2d Thanks! But "shopping answers" would be cool, I'm willing to DIY but have few clues in this arena, never heard of anything winny is referring to.

Comment: I guess load is a 14V battery to be charged? Then, what power supply will be used? AC mains? Or some DC source, in which case please state its voltage...

Comment: the voltage is closely regulated, currently want to use 13.8, and yes, a large bank of batteries. As stated just above there are many different possible charge sources, looking for something to "throttle" the bank's much higher than 50A draw in order to avoid damaging those sources without current limiting overload protection.

Comment: @laptop2d Wow, didn't realize others could edit my question, thanks I guess, but I had to re-edit it again so it fits what I'm after. If you need to adjust any further let me know, thanks.

Comment: @HansBKK just trying to keep it on-topic, off topic questions are closed

Comment: I don't really get what this question is after. Seeing how no one else really got it either, I'm VTC unclear.

Comment: Indeed, this question is problematic - and far too broad.  Also the idea of stacking charge sources in parallel is extremely worrisome, at minimum such usage would have to have been contemplated when designing those sources, which is usually not the case.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what a "powerful charge source" or a "very large depleted bank of low resistance / high acceptance rate chemistry" is, but...

For these currents, I'd use teamwork.

Using a DC-DC chip intended for LED drivers or battery charging applications, we can build a buck voltage-limited current source, say 5-10A at 14V.

Then we stack them in parallel. These could be purchased pre-built.

To get 50A in a single design, you are likely to need lots of paralleled MOSFETs... and a multiphase buck controller, high copper weight PCB... I'd use 4 phases.

Comment: see above for charge source examples. LiFePO4 is an example such chemistry, commonly used for electric vehicles' battery banks. As opposed to lead, where the high resistance inherently limits the current the bank will accept.

Comment: Note the voltage will already be exactly where it needs to be, no DCDC conversion is needed, just current limiting.

Comment: And in fact I will need to be able to make Voltage adjustments as needed, as all the charge sources' regulation allow. Just that some are missing the current limiting functionality needed. Do not assume mains/grid power is available, usually it will not be.